# How to fetch all properties of apex class object using helper.js function in lighting component in Community portal

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura, customer-community

When passing list of object of apex from controller to helper js, we couldn't access properties of each object. We can see the count is shown correct in js function, but can't see/access property.

Controller Function:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<FullCalendarEvent> getEventSObjects () {

    List<FullCalendarEvent> lstFullCalendarEvent = new List<FullCalendarEvent>();

    ##Fetch Data & process##

    return lstFullCalendarEvent

}
```

helper js function:

```
getEvents: function(component,recordIds) {
    console.log('in getEventList');
    var action = component.get("c.getEventSObjects");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        console.log('error',response.getError());
        console.log('response',response.getReturnValue());
        console.log('state'+state);
        if (state == "SUCCESS") {
            console.log('events',response.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.events", response.getReturnValue());
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

[image: Can't see/access js object properties]

Comment: What did you specify for 'events' attribute type? And can you post the structure of FullCalendarEvent? Do you get any errors? Posting your markup will also help us identify the cause.

Comment: To be able to access properties of an apex class on client side, you need to make sure that the properties are marked as `@AuraEnabled` in the class

Comment: @JayantDas: You were right, we hadn't marked properties as AuraEnabled. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rolling up comments as an answer.

If you want to access properties from a wrapper class on a lightning component, you need to have this marked as `@AuraEnabled`. Refer to this excerpt from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_auraenabled_annotation.htm):

> Use @AuraEnabled on Apex instance methods and **properties** to make them serializable when an instance of the class is returned as **data** from a server-side action.

As was in this case, the wrapper class is returned as "data" and thus should have the properties marked accordingly to be accessible on your component.